# Injecting the application TransactionManager into a JPA EntityListener

Tags: java, spring, security, jpa, acl

I want to use the JPA EntityListener to support spring security ACLs.
On `@PostPersist` events, I create a permission corresponding to the persisted entity.

I need this operation to participate to the current Transaction.
For this to happen I need to have a reference to the application `TransactionManager` in the `EntityListener`.

The problem is, Spring can't manage the `EntityListener` as it is created automatically when `EntityManagerFactory` is instantiated.
And in a classic Spring app, the `EntityManagerFactory` is itself created during the `TransactioManager` instantiation.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

So I have no way to inject the `TransactionManager` with the constructor, as it is not yet instantiated.

Making the `EntityManager` a `@Component` create another instance of the `EntityManager`.
Implementing InitiliazingBean and using `afterPropertySet()` doesn't work as it's not a Spring managed bean.

Any idea would be helpful as I'm stuck and out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to nodje's instruction you should add one more thing - add AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect as dependency for your entity manager, otherwise your entity listeners will be created BEFORE spring context will be initialized:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    depends-on="org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect">
```

Comment: And one more thing here. If you use DB as storage for your quartz scheduler, then don't set JpaTransactionManager as transaction manager for quartz, otherwise you'll get circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use Spring's @Configurable annotation on the EntityListener.

It should in theory allow a non Spring managed instance, the EntityListener in my case, to be aspect woven and thus allowing this instance to get DI.

So here're the different steps:

- add @Configurable to the EntityListener and @Autowired on the filed to inject (TransactionManager here)
- add `<context:spring-configured/>` to the Spring context
- use aspects-maven-plugin to do Compile Time Weaving (see config below)

So far so good, but it's not working for me. The logs says the EntityListerner is woven:

```
[INFO] Extending interface set for type 'org.project.commons.security.DefaultEntityListener' (DefaultEntityListener.java) to include 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.ConfigurableObject' (AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aj)
[INFO] Join point 'initialization(void org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.ConfigurableObject.<init>())' in Type 'org.project.commons.security.DefaultEntityListener' (DefaultEntityListener.java:38) advised by before advice from 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect' (spring-aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar!AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.class:78(from AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] Join point 'initialization(void org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.ConfigurableObject.<init>())' in Type 'org.project.commons.security.DefaultEntityListener' (DefaultEntityListener.java:38) advised by afterReturning advice from 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect' (spring-aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar!AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.class:87(from AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] Join point 'initialization(void org.project.commons.security.DefaultEntityListener.<init>())' in Type 'org.project.commons.security.DefaultEntityListener' (DefaultEntityListener.java:38) advised by afterReturning advice from 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect' (spring-aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar!AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.class:87(from AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
```

but I never get the expected injection.

I anyone has a clue, I welcome it...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <proceedOnError>true</proceedOnError>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>${encoding}</encoding>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <weaveDependencies>
                    <weaveDependency>
                        <groupId>org.project</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
                    </weaveDependency>
                </weaveDependencies>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!--<goal>test-compile</goal>-->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```